# Two object of same type in spring controller's method (session and non session) non session is replacing session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have a method in Spring controller which accepts two arguments which are of same type
and one of them is coming from session and another is coming from a form submission(UI).

The problem is that at the controller method my non session object is replacing my session object.I am not sure it is some bug or i am making some silly mistakes.

spring version 3.1.2 
spring mvc/ mvc-web 3.1.0

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tspadmin")
@SessionAttributes({"currentUser"})
public class TSPAdminUserController {

@Autowired
private TSPAdminUserService tspAdminUserService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser")
public @ResponseBody Object createUser(User user,@ModelAttribute("currentUser")   User currentUser){

             //Here user(from UI) object is replacing currentUser
    //processing
}
}
```

I am doing this because here one user is creating another user and i want to set some session user's property to another user before persisting.

view:

```
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    password: function(val, field) {
        if (field.initialPassField) {
            var pwd = field.up('form').down('#' + field.initialPassField);
            return (val == pwd.getValue());
        }
        return true;
    },

    passwordText: 'Passwords does not not match'
});


var create_user = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
extend:'Ext.form.Formpanel',
autoScroll: true,
title: 'Create User',

border:false,
layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
renderTo: document.body,
items : [ {
    xtype : 'panel',
    border : false,
    margin : '20 20 20 20',
    width : '40%',
    defaults : {

        width : 300

    },

    items : [
        //comboboxs.tspNameCombo,

        {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            allowBlank : false,
            fieldLabel : 'User Name',
            name : 'userName',
            width : 350,
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            regex: /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/,
              regexText: "<b>Error</b></br>Password should be of minimum 8 character length, it should be alphanumeric ,must contain at least one special character,one Upper case letter.",
             validator: function(v) {
             return  /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/.test(v)?true:"Invalid Number";
             },
            id: 'pass'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Confirm Password',
            name: 'confirmPassword',
            vtype: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            initialPassField: 'pass' // id of the initial password field
        },
        {
            xtype : 'textfield',
            allowBlank : false,
            fieldLabel : 'Email',
            name : 'email',
            vtype : 'email',
            width : 350,

        },  {
            xtype:"textfield",
            allowBlank : true,
            regex: /^[0-9\+\-_]+$/,
            fieldLabel: 'Telephone Number',
            name: 'telephone1',
            regexText: "<b>Error</b></br>Invalid Number entered.",
            validator: function(v) {
                return /^[0-9\+\-_]+$/.test(v)?true:"Invalid Number";
            }
        },

        {
            xtype:"textfield",
            allowBlank : false,
            regex: /^[0-9\+\-_]+$/,
            fieldLabel: 'Mobile Number',
            name: 'telephone2',
            regexText: "<b>Error</b></br>Invalid Number entered.",
            validator: function(v) {
                return /^[0-9\+\-_]+$/.test(v)?true:"Invalid Number";
            }
        },
    ]
}],
buttonAlign:'left',
buttons: [{
    text: 'Save',
    margin : '20 20 20 20',
    handler: function () {
        var form = create_user.getForm();
        form.submit({
            url:'tspadmin/createUser',
            success : function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success',action.result.message,function(){
                    location.reload();
                });
            },
            failure : function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure',action.result.message);
            }

        });
    }
}, {
    text: 'Cancel',
    margin:'20 20 20 20',
    handler: function() {
        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
    }
},

]


});
```

Comment: please post the view(JSP) code. Are u using Spring Form tlds? If your binding form elements to model u sud have your "user" object also as part Model ( @ModelAttribute("user") User user ). Im assuming your newly created user data is being populated from a Form.

Comment: I am using Extjs as view part and not binding form elements to model.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs 
SessionAttributes:`"This will typically list the names of model attributes which should be transparently stored in the session or some conversational storage, serving as form-backing beans"` 
Your code work right, you just use the wrong thing.

Take a look at this: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/

If you want to store and get the user from the session:
1) Create session bean that hold the user info and inject it in the controller(use aop:scoped-proxy) 
2) Store the User directly in the session and add HttpSession argument in the controller method.
3) Spring Security has some utilities to store the logged user

Comment: I appreciate but problem is not with getting or setting session attributes.... that is working fine. The fact is why my non session object(user) which is coming from UI is replacing the session object(currentUser).

Comment: How you tell spring that the first argument(user) should come from the session? I guess that for this parameter spring tries to inject a bean with the same type, which is the user from the model attribute.